# Why didn't Arya use the powers of The Faceless Men to get past the dead in the library?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the War of Winterfell in *Game of Thrones* S08E03, we see Arya terrified in the library. Why didn't she change herself to appear as the dead in order to get past them?

Comment: I think Paulie_D's answer sums it up as best one can, but I think there is nothing wrong with asking questions based on magical semantics, even if we don't have a lot of evidence to support a possibility of something being asked. It's not impossible assumption, just not a lot of evidence to support it would work 1+

Comment: Sure. I want to keep the question open for some more time, to read other people's perspective.

Comment: Ya, I mean there may be something to the condition to what one's face needs to be in order to use it. So maybe Arya didn't have the time to prepair it either? Plus I think there are many characters that are "living-dead", but the semantics on them have been different...

Comment: At what point between the opening scene and the library did she have the opportunity to collect an undead face?   If she doesn't even have time to perform that first step then there's nothing else to consider.

Comment: She didn't us her powers? Seems like she pretty much disappeared without a sight when the wight heard her blood drip. Also, it doesn't seem like visual reception is the kind of dominating factor for the undead as the living.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Because appearing dead is not the same as being dead.

Firstly, we do not know the extent of the shape-shifting abilities of the Faceless Men but these appear to be based on *appearing* as something other than what you are.

The Dead are targeting the living and there is no indication that the abilities of the Faceless Men can make you be sensed as "unliving" to the Dead.

Essentially, if Arya is alive, she's targeted by the Dead, **regardless of what she looks like**.